# html5 based game not working in android

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, html5-canvas

I have an html5 game that was designed that will not work on android phones. The client is saving their website to their android device as a webapp and when they open the app from their homescreen, when they click on the link for the game, all they are getting is a black screen. I am thinking that because they are getting this issue, when they save the app to their phone, it is saving a cached version and will not allow the necessary files to load for the game. When they try this on the desktop, it works perfectly, as well when they try on any apple device it will work, only because when you click a link on a webapp saved to the homescreen on an apple device it breaks out of the shell and opens safari browser.

Is there any way to make the link to the game break out of an android webapp that is saved to the homescreen so that it can open in a web browser instead of inside the app?

Any suggestions are welcome.

The link to the app is http://mobilesourceapps.com/pondwiser

Thanks again guys!

Answer (score -2):

Try PhoneGap. An auto-builder. http://phonegap.com/ it will compile the mobile versions for Android. There is also a version-download for IOS from the App Store. This might help you. Without code is tricky.